# MousExited doesn't get fired on JDialog with GlassPane, MouseEntered does

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog, mouselistener

I have made an own Window-Model, which extend JFrame and JDialog, without Window-Decoration. If I make a new window, its a instanciation of the respective model. To handle resizing of these windows, I have added the [well behaved glass pane](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/alexfromsun/archive/2006/09/a_wellbehaved_g.html) to these models. The GlassPane is added like this to the frame/dialog

```
//here, I create a new GlassPane and give it the instance of the JFrame/JDialog, so the
AWT-Listener in the GlassPane can resize this instance.
glassPane = new GlassPane(this, res, valWidth, valHeight, RESIZEBORDER,
            BORDERPIXEL, isResizable, keepRatio);
//then I set this GlassPane to the JFame/JDialog
this.setGlassPane(glassPane);

//this is from the example. I'm not absolutly sure, what it does.             
if (this.glassPane instanceof AWTEventListener) {
        AWTEventListener al = (AWTEventListener) glassPane;
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(
                al,
                AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK
                        | AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);
    }
glassPane.setVisible(true);
    glassPane.repaint();
```

In the GlassPane, I have modified the events from the example like this:

```
public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
    if (event instanceof MouseEvent) {


            //I convert the MouseEvent like in the example
    MouseEvent e = (MouseEvent)event;

    if (target instanceof JFrame) {
            e = SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent(
            ((MouseEvent) event).getComponent(),
            (MouseEvent) event, ((JFrame) target).getGlassPane());
        } else if (target instanceof JDialog) {
            e = SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent(
                    ((MouseEvent) event).getComponent(),
                    (MouseEvent) event, this);
        }

        if (!SwingUtilities.isDescendingFrom(e.getComponent(), target)) {
            return;

        }
                    //I check the events like this
        if (e.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED) {
            System.out.println("exit");
        }
```

Now to my problem:

If I open a JFrame and this frame opens a JDialog, all the resizing works. Also the MOUSE_ENTERS-Event gets fired if I move my cursor onto the JDialog. But the MOUSE_EXITED-Event only gets fired if I move the cursor out of the JDialog and ALSO out of the JFrame.
Another Problem is, that the Mouse_Entered-Event gets fired twice: The first one gets fired by the GlassPane of the JDialog, and the second one gets fired by the GlassPane of the JFrame. I have also tried to add a MouseListener directly to the JFrame/JDialog, but this has the same effect. Maybe this is important: I have set the JFrame as owner of the JDialog.

I dont't know why it's behaving like this..
I hope, somebody can help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To handle resizing of these windows...

See [Resizing Components](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/13/resizing-components/) for a solution that might be simpler.

Comment: Ok, I've tested it and now the resizing is much more simpler and works great. But I still have this Mouse_Exited Problem. So it wasn't the fault of the GlassPanel. What else could be the problem?

Comment: I found the source of the problem. The Mouse_Exited-Event doesn't get fired on JDialogs without decoration.